# How to download ARImage (.SCN) file to display image in ARSCNView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I am trying to download the **ARImage(.scn file)** In my application.  And display in the **ARSCNView**

Below my code is working fine it's able to display the image. An image is also below

```
func addARObject(x: Float = 0, y: Float = 0, z: Float = -0.5) {

    let aRUrl : URL = URL(string :arImageUrl2)!
    do {
        let arScene = try SCNScene(url: aRUrl  , options: nil)
        let arNode = arScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "chair", recursively: false)
        print("x,y,z",x,y,z)
        arNode?.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)

        zAxis = z
        if isNodeAvailable {
            currentNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
        }else{
            isNodeAvailable = true
            currentNode = arNode
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(arNode!)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("errrrrororororor")
    }

}
```

And Output of this is  
[image]

But **chair** color is **Red** and its showing surface white color. but actually, there is no surface.

**If the same image I am using In My project folder Without download then chair color is Red.
So Can Anyone Explain to me what's wrong with my code or image issue?**

Below Image is when I am using the local File in my Project.

[image]

Comment: Get child node of chair and set materials manually for chair child nodes.

Comment: @PvDev How I will get All Child name?

Comment: hey i have answered your question..let me know if it works..

Answer (score 0):

You create a parent node and then you can add all your nodes as children.

```
var nodes: [SCNNode] = getMyNodes()

var parentNode = SCNNode()
parentNode.name = "chair"

for node in nodes {
parentNode.addChildNodes(node)
}
```

You can access a specific child using:

```
 parentNode.childNode(withName: nameOfChildNode, recursively: true)
```

If you are importing from a scene file:

```
 let scene = SCNScene(named: "myScene.scn")

  func getMyNodes() -> [SCNNode] {
  var nodes: [SCNNode] = [SCNNode]()
  for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    nodes.append(node)
   }
   return nodes
 }
```

After getting child node from parent node, you can add texture to the child node.

```
  let childOne = parentNode.childNode(withName: nameOfChildNode, recursively: true)

  childOne.?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
```